# Spot welding technique

Tags: experimental-technique, hall-effect

I am trying to make electrical contacts by the spot welding technique. For Hall effect measurements, the contact size should be as small as possible and the sample  is very very thin (0.025mm). But while spot welding, i am somehow able to make contacts, but it creates a hole in my sample. How to get rid of it? Is there any other way of making such fine contacts on such thin samples?

Comment: I suppose this is for the voltage sensing contacts. Silver paint would be ok. For the current connection, the contact size should be large so that the current can be large.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several, as follows.

First there is thermosonic bonding, in which a heated tool applies local pressure to the two pieces being bonded, and then a burst of ultrasound is used to vibrate that tool. This technique is used to make contact between a silicon chip and a kapton/gold flexible leadframe (or "flex circuit") in a process called TAB or *Tape Automated Bonding*.

Second, you can try *solderbonding*, in which a paste containing finely milled solder particles is silkscreened onto (for example) a printed circuit board, and a silicon chip is then placed upside-down atop the solder paste areas and heated. The solder melts and connects the PC board to the interconnect pads on the chip in what is known as the *flip-chip* process.

Third, you can glue the parts together using an epoxy containing finely milled silver spherules which is called *conductive epoxy*.